# Any Canonical model to be considered using Apache Camel for integration

Tags: apache-camel, integration, activemq-classic, esb, canonical-schema

I am new to Camel and little aware of Integration technologies, so please help me understand

As I read from camel docs, **Camel supports a pluggable DataFormat to allow messages to be marshalled to and from binary or text formats to support a kind of Message Translator.**

So far from integration framework point of view I assume the integration framework has a standard(say X) canonical format where messages from any end point are
converted to X on entry, and while giving to any other endpoint, X is transformed to corresponding endpoint format and vice versa.

Also as I observed the `org.apache.camel.Exchange` being the key object used to transfer the state between each endpoint, the actual data can be plugged with any object like,

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(Object.class);
exchange.getIn().setBody(new Object());
```

This makes me assume any java object can be holded in body in a route

So does camel has any specific data format or it supports any format that can be plugged and the developer needs to maintain a consistent format(say X) where
transformation from/to happens to X on uri:from/uri:to

I am not sure if I am assuming and ESB as Integration framework, but I have above doubts

Please suggest some references for understanding this Canonical model of camel better

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own `TypeConverter` classes to convert between your canonical form and whatever other data types.

Please have a look at [Apache Camel Type Converter](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html)

Write the converters using the `@Converter` annotations and define them in the `TypeConverter` file (at the specific location mentioned in the documentation). Then the converters will be automatically used in camel routes when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Camel support multiple ways to transform the body of an Exchange such as DataFormats, TypeConveters, or custom Processors.

In general, you will probably need to transform the body of an Exchange when interacting with external systems due to the coupling between Endpoints and the Exchange they produce/consume. Endpoints expects some particular content in the body of the Exchange they handle. For example, the Mail Endpoint producer (used to send emails) expect the body of an email message as the body of the Exchange. The CXF Component may expect a JAXB annotated POJO as the body of the exchange, which will be marshalled to XML. The File and Ftp Components can handled File, byte[] or String on different circumstances.

However, the choice of Exchange body inside you routes is completely up to you.

If you want to use Camel just as an integration framework (to move data between systems) you probably will only need to transform the data from source format (Exchange generated by the Consumer Endpoint) to the destination format (Exchange send to the Producer Endpoint).

If you want to use Camel to implement a more complex business logic pipeline, it might be appropriate to use an specialized message. In my experience, using a POJO as Exchange body works just fine in this cases, as long as the routes passing the message are in the same JVM. If you need to send the message to a remote JVM (maybe via JMS) I recommend explicitly marshalling the message as XML or JSON message rather than sending the serialized Java object.

Comment: I feel using remote JVM's or any other platforms like C# or Python etc, XML or JSON might be the good canonical form(Specialized Message) to be carried in Exchange. Then I need to convert the specialized message to endpoint type(FILE, FTP, Web service, MQ etc) and send it. On receiving back again convert from endpoint type(FILE, FTP, Web service, MQ etc) to specialized message. So 2 converters for hitting each endpoint. `.convertBodyTo(CannonicalToEndpointType.class)
 .to("endpoint") .convertBodyTo(EndpointToCannonicalType.class)`

Comment: Found a good article here, http://erwin.com/community/expert-blogs/the-canonical-data-model/